# How do you write a Bash script that runs a C++ program?

Tags: c++, bash, sockets

The functionality of the C++ program is to open a computer socket (1 of the 16) to allow software programs to be downloaded onto it. My script is suppose to take that program and invoke it 16 different times because there are 16 different nodes (all different IP addresses). Where do I even start??? I am very new to Bash scripting.

Comment: What's the problem?  Just invoke the program 16 times in your script.

Comment: So, what have you tried so far? I'd probably just write the same thing [with difference in the IP address] 16 times over.

Comment: I'm an intern and they kind of just threw this assignment on me. I have never scripted anything before. And im FREAKING OUT.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a simple script like this (if your executable is `a.out`:

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out arg1 arg2 ...
./a.out arg1 arg2 ...
#.. do this 16 times
```

Basically, just put the command that you use to run your `C++` program in your bash script 16 times, and put `#!/bin/bash` at the top.

Afterwards, you can do a `chmod +x shellScriptName.sh` to make your script executable, and then run it!

Comment: What would my arguments be?

Comment: Whatever arguments you normally use to run your C++ program.  You might not have any arguments, and that is normal.

Comment: But the IP address within the program would be different for each one. so how do i run it 16 times with a certain IP address each time?? @jh314

Comment: You can specify the ip as an argument to your C++ program